# Sort by price when price is set in multiple keys

Tags: wordpress, sorting, woocommerce

I am performing a query, using WP_Query.
I am trying to sort products by price ( from lowest to highest ), and I have a problem, namely that the price value is set in the key "_price" in some products, and in the key "_phive_booking_pricing_base_cost" in other products.

I am testing by sending WP_Query the following arguments:

```
Array
(
    [post_type] => product
    [tax_query] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [taxonomy] => product_cat
                    [field] => slug
                    [terms] => excursiones
                )

        )

    [s] => 
    [order] => ASC
    [orderby] => Array
        (
            [_price_clause] => ASC
            [_phive_booking_pricing_base_cost_clause] => ASC
        )

    [posts_per_page] => 5
    [paged] => 1
    [post_status] => publish
    [meta_query] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [relation] => OR
                    [_price_clause] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => _price
                            [compare] => EXISTS
                        )

                    [_phive_booking_pricing_base_cost_clause] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => _phive_booking_pricing_base_cost
                            [compare] => EXISTS
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

But I can't get the system to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a `WP_Query` solution per se, but I had some performance issues with more complex WP queries in past. An **alternative solution** might be to retrieve already sorted products with SQL query to an array of product IDs and then use it in your WP_Query.

This is a simple example - it checks for the `_price` first, and only if it doesn't exist it checks for the `_phive_booking_pricing_base_cost`. Then, it orders the products by prices:

```sql
SELECT post_id, meta_value 
FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE meta_key = '_price' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT post_id, meta_value 
FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE meta_key = '_phive_booking_pricing_base_cost' AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM wp_postmeta 
    WHERE meta_key = '_price'
)
ORDER BY meta_value DESC;
```

Once you have the array of product IDs, you can use `post__in` argument for your `WP_Query` (don't forget to alter the `orderby` arg as well, to keep the ordering):

```
$args = array (
    'post__in' => $product_ids,
    'orderby' => 'post__in' 
);
```